# Deploying Laravel 4 on shared hosting server (hostgator)

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I would appreciate your help. I really don't know where else to turn to. I can't deploy a L4 app to Hostgator. I read the guide on the forums, but my shared HG account already has many apps under public_html so deleting it would be catastrophic and a risk I cannot afford to play with.

Is there a way to deploy L4 app like any other normal apps?

What I am trying to do is the following:

```
home/myuser/public_html/domain.com/laravel/               <--- where the app should live
home/myuser/public_html/domain.com/laravel/dev          <--- dev environment
```

in both of these folders there is a separate git repository (via ssh). with remotes dev and prod

so what I simply want to achieve is:

```
git push prod
```

and

```
git push dev
```

but when I push, I am getting a message:

```
dev/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php) [function.require]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory

/dev/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/opt/php53/lib/php') in
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out I had not installed Composer properly.
I solved this by:

adding alias to php 5.3 in .bashrc:

```
alias php53='/opt/php53/bin/php'
```

installing Composer:

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php53
```

in composer.json, in the "scripts" replacing php with: `/opt/php53/bin/php` (alias is not accepted, do not know why)

running

```
php53 composer.phar install
```

adding to .htaccess:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php53 .php
```

Comment: So you have success deploy laravel project in Hostgator? I'm thinking to take a plan in Hostgator for deploy my Laravel 4 project too

Comment: Yes, but you should check it out with Hostgator support now - it has been more than a year so I think they support PHP 5.3+ out of the box. If that is the case it should be much simpler for you to deploy it.

Answer (score 0):

I created a repository to simplify the installation process(mostly for future visitors) after struggling with it several times.

You can find the repository at https://github.com/ralphowino/laravel-for-hostgator-users or download it via https://github.com/ralphowino/laravel-for-hostgator-users/archive/master.zip

Comment: Cool! I will try it out and let you know how it went. At least I know now that I was not the only one struggling with Laravel on Hostgator.

Comment: Thanks. Would be keen to hear how it went

Comment: Zico, please give more details? what happened?