# Laravel 4 bootstrap error

Tags: php, json, laravel, composer-php

This is the error I get after everything is installed:

These are the steps I did to install.

1. Downloaded XAMPP
2. Opened command terminal from root user:

   ```
    git clone -b develop git://github.com/laravel/laravel.git L4_site
   ```
3. Change directory cd L4_site
4. Create a composer.json file in the root or install by terminal:

   ```
   curl -S getcomposer.org/installer|php -d detect_unicode=off
   ```

   *See chris-schmitz.com/getting-started-with-laravel-4
5. In L4_site directory in terminal type: php composer.phar install

   ```
   This is the error I got after installing composer:
   Strikers-MacBook-Pro:L4_site striker$ php composer.phar install
   Loading composer repositories with package information
   Installing dependencies (including require-dev)
   Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
   ```
6. Then point server, type:

   ```
   php -S localhost:8888 -t public/
   ```

After I did all this I copied the directory to my hosted server (hostgator) and get the below error:

```
>Warning: require(/home/flemzy/public_html/l/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php)     [function.require]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/flemzy/public_html/l/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17

>Fatal error: require() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/home/flemzy/public_html/l/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/opt/php53/lib/php') in /home/flemzy/public_html/l/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17
```

I am so close to getting a working laravel 4 beginning app. The error lies somewhere in the dependencies not being installed properly. I think I need a correct composer.json file in order to get ride of these errors.

Thank you everyone for your help.

Comment: HostGator provides SSH. Have you tried installing directly on the server? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18281624/deploying-laravel-4-on-shared-hosting-server-hostgator.

Comment: I uploaded my directory to my hostgator server. I have shared server hosting.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in step 4), you should do:

```
 curl -S getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

and then

```
 php composer.phar install
```

See https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#locally for detailed instructions to install Composer

Comment: I did curl composer first and them php composer.phar install. Step 5 is php composer.phar install

Comment: Ok, I see you edited the question, It seems you have an invalid composer.json

Comment: where can I get a valid composer.json file

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/composer.json Anyway, avoid using the develop branch in step 1 and -d detect_unicode=off in step 4, and follow the official guide for a fresh install: http://laravel.com/docs/installation